# Solving for unknown upper bound of the integral

Tags: r, integral, equation-solving

I am trying to implement an algorithm in `R` that involves solving for the boundary limit of the integral. For example, I want to find `a` given the following integral:

`integral_0^a exp(x) = 1/2`

I have a rough idea how to do it in `matlab`. But how would one go about solving this in `R`?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `integrate` to compute the integral (numerically)
and `uniroot` to solve the equation (numerically).

```
f <- function(a) integrate( exp, 0, a )$value - 1/2
uniroot( f, c(-1, 1) ) # Look for a solution in [-1,1]
log(3/2) # Compare with the exact solution
```